# Custom Retry strategy for Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient

I'm using a fixedRetry in order to repeat HTTP calls using WebClient.
I want the first retry to be called after 5 minutes, the second one after 30 minutes, and the rest after 60 minutes. Is there a way to do this using the fixedRetry? I checked https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-retry several times, but I haven't found a way to use 3 different values for the delay time.

This how the constructor looks like:

```
public MyService(WebClient client,
            @Value("${retry.quantity}") int retries,
            @Value("${retry.time.first}") int firstTime,
            @Value("${retry.time.second}") int secondTime,
            @Value("${retry.time.rest}") int restTime) 
{
        this.client = client;
        this.fixedRetry = Retry.anyOf(ResponseException.class)
                .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(restTime))
                .retryMax(retries)
                .doOnRetry(exception ->
                    log.error("Exception on Retry is {} .", exception)
                );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement custom `Retry` to achieve this. Here is an example

```
private static class CustomRetrySpec extends Retry {
    private final int retries;
    private final Duration firstTime;
    private final Duration secondTime;
    private final Duration restTime;

    public CustomRetrySpec(int retries, Duration firstTime, Duration secondTime, Duration restTime) {
        this.retries = retries;
        this.firstTime = firstTime;
        this.secondTime = secondTime;
        this.restTime = restTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<?> generateCompanion(Flux<RetrySignal> retrySignals) {
        return retrySignals.flatMap(this::getRetry);
    }

    private Mono<Long> getRetry(Retry.RetrySignal rs) {
        if (rs.totalRetries() < retries) {
            Duration delay;
            if (rs.totalRetries() == 0) {
                delay = firstTime;
            } else if (rs.totalRetries() == 1) {
                delay = secondTime;
            } else {
                delay = restTime;
            }

            log.debug("retry {} with backoff {}min", rs.totalRetries(), delay.toMinutes());
            return Mono.delay(delay)
                    .thenReturn(rs.totalRetries());
        } else {
            log.debug("retries exhausted with error: {}", rs.failure().getMessage());
            throw Exceptions.propagate(rs.failure());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a test using `StepVerifier.withVirtualTime`

```
@Test
void testCustomRetrySpec() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() ->
                    process()
                            .retryWhen(new CustomRetrySpec(3,
                                    Duration.ofMinutes(5),
                                    Duration.ofMinutes(30),
                                    Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                            )
            )
            .expectSubscription()
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
            .expectError()
            .verify();

}

private Mono<?> process() {
    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("oops"));
}
```

Comment: I apologize I didn't confirm earlier, but this totally worked! Thanks a lot!