# Dynamic Backoff duration in RetryBackoffSpec in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> sendRequestToServer(params))
        .doOnSuccess(result -> handleResponse(result, grantMapEntry, deviceInfo))
        .retryWhen(RetryBackoffSpec
            .backoff(5, ofSeconds(10))
            .doAfterRetry(retryInfo -> {
                  log.warn("retrying");
             })
            .scheduler(hbRetryScheduler)
            .jitter(0.5);)
        .subscribe();
```

Above spec. works fine, but the problem is sometimes server is not able to process the request and returns 106 response code with retryTime in seconds (seconds after which the request should be retried with backoff and jitter). How can I use the returned retryTime in RetryBackoffSpec?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72779662/9068895

Comment: @Alex everywhere its using predefined delay and retries. In my case I'll get the delay in handleResponse() response and there is no way to pass it to retryBackoff spec.

Comment: not sure I'm following, but delay is initialized `delay = ...;`.  you can still do `delay = calculateDelay();`

Comment: Let's assime handleResponse returns an int value representing the amout of delay for next retry. How can I use the return value in RetryBackoffSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom `RetrySpec` based on criteria from the `RetrySignal` (e.g. http headers from the response).

The following example uses `Retry-After` header to define custom backoff logic.

```
private static class DynamicRetrySpec extends Retry {
    private final int maxRetries;
    private final Duration defaultBackoff;

    public DynamicRetrySpec(int maxRetries, Duration defaultBackoff) {
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
        this.defaultBackoff = defaultBackoff;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<?> generateCompanion(Flux<RetrySignal> retrySignals) {
        return retrySignals.flatMap(this::getRetry);
    }

    private Mono<Long> getRetry(Retry.RetrySignal rs) {
        if (rs.failure() instanceof WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests) {
            if (rs.totalRetries() < maxRetries) {
                Duration delay = getBackOffDelayFromHeaders((WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests) rs.failure());

                log.info("retry {} with backoff {}sec", rs.totalRetries(), delay.toSeconds());
                return Mono.delay(delay)
                        .thenReturn(rs.totalRetries());
            } else {
                log.info("retries exhausted with error: {}", rs.failure().getMessage());
                throw Exceptions.propagate(rs.failure());
            }
        } else {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(rs.failure());
        }
    }

    private Duration getBackOffDelayFromHeaders(WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests exceptionResponse) {
        String retryAfter = exceptionResponse.getHeaders().getFirst("Retry-After");
        if (retryAfter != null) {
            return Duration.ofSeconds(Integer.parseInt(retryAfter));
        }
        return defaultBackoff;
    }
}
```

and then uses it to the `WebClient`

```
webClient.get()
    .uri("/api")
    .retrieve()
    .toBodilessEntity()
    .retryWhen(new DynamicRetrySpec(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```